# Before sending the envelope - option to view envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocusignAPI, I do want to view the envelope like recipient view. I searched for the "Post Recipient View", this can be done only for the sent envelope. In the "Post Envelope correction" I am able to see the tags and also able to delete/reupload the documents. I would like to view only the documents with their prefilled tag values. Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the various DocuSign recipient types.  For instance, there is the `carbonCopy` recipient who doesn't take any action on the envelope but just gets a copy and they can be inserted at any routing order in the envelope.

There's also some of the other recipient types with various permissions that can change recipient info for people who are later in the routing order, such as the `agent` and `intermediary` recipient types.

See [this page](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipient%20Parameter.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7CSend%2520an%2520Envelope%2520or%2520Create%2520a%2520Draft%2520Envelope%7CRecipient%2520Parameters%7C_____0) from the REST API Docs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to implement this before sending to actual users. Like download envelope documents/combined option in the REST api. while downloading the document the data which are is filled not available. The user should not edit the tags/document he should only have the option to view documents with filled values in tags.

Comment: What exactly is your use case?  If the first person will only view the document(s) why does it matter if the envelope has been sent or not?  Tabs are always specific for recipients, not the document itself, so you won't see the values until you set them to something and send to a recipient.